# Why laravel define validation in controller instead of Eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel

I am reading [the laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation), and there is some doubt about validation

If the web server will provide web interface to desktop user, and api interface to mobile user, there is a problem: It will define validation twice in api controller and web controller, it is duplication.

and if there is a another co-developer to develop a large project, He should to know previous developer defined validation, it is not good for collaborative development

I think It should define validation logic in same place, Like ActiveRecord in Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Request file in the Requests folder and inject this file in controller method and it will automatically validate the request. Please continue reading the Laravel validation documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) and you will find this method elaborately.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method to the Models like 'getValidator' which gives you the validator, and then in the controller you just ask this.

However a validator would most of the time want to validate the input from the (user) input. Imagine input that has to be applied to multiple models or complex relationships. It would be strange to say the validation is really part of the/one model. In the end it just validates the input, so you need it in your controller.

A better way of abstracting in your case might be to interpret the 'web' part als *also* an app, which connects to your API. And then let the API be the only way to interact with your backend, and thus having the validation only in 1 place (the API).

In the end, it's up to you how you structure it.